# How to use a loop to select items sequentially within Android app

Tags: java, android, while-loop, automation, appium

**Here I have 3 images with clickable elements :**

[image]

I used this code so when it runs through the first loop, it selects the **FIRST** image :

`driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle")).click();`

After my code runs through the second loop, I want it to go back and select the **SECOND** image, and so on.

**I've obtained my elements from uiautomatorviewer which can be seen here :**

[image]

I am not sure on what command to use to fix my problem, could anyone help me out?

**Here is my full code for better examination :**

```
public void SimpleTest() throws InterruptedException {


driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/email_button")).click(); 

By path = By.xpath("//*[@text='Enter your email address']"); 

driver.findElement(path).sendKeys("xxxxx@gmail.com");
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/next_button")).click(); 

By path1 = By.xpath("//*[@text='']"); 

driver.findElement(path1).sendKeys("xxxxx");

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/main_text")).click(); 
Thread.sleep(10000);

By path2 = By.xpath("//*[@text='OfferUp']"); 

driver.findElement(path2).click(); 
Thread.sleep(10000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/nav_post_item")).click(); 
Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/addPhotoFromGallery")).click();

try {

driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/dir_thumbnail")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/medium_thumbnail")).click();
}

catch (Exception e) {

    driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/done")).click();
}

By path3 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Name, brand, model, etc.']");

driver.findElement(path3).sendKeys("Iphone icloud unlocked"); 

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/see_more")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/category_list_row_text"));

By path4 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Cell Phones']");

driver.findElement(path4).click();

By path5 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Description']");

driver.findElement(path5).sendKeys("");
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/conditionSeekBar")).sendKeys(new CharSequence[] { " " }); 

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();

By path6 = By.xpath("//*[@text='$0']"); 

driver.findElement(path6).sendKeys("200"); 
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/firmPrice")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/edit")).click();

By path7 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Zip code']");

driver.findElement(path7).sendKeys("xxxx"); 
Thread.sleep(2000); 

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/saveLocation")).click();  

if(driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/shipping_checkbox")).isSelected()){
       driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/shipping_checkbox")).click();
    }

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();

driver.closeApp();
Thread.sleep(50000); 

int index = 100;
do {
    index --;

By path8 = By.xpath("//*[@text='OfferUp']"); 

driver.findElement(path8).click(); 
Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/nav_post_item")).click(); 
Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/addPhotoFromGallery")).click();

try {

driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/dir_thumbnail")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/medium_thumbnail")).click();
}

catch (Exception e) {

    driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/done")).click();
}

By path9 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Name, brand, model, etc.']");

driver.findElement(path9).sendKeys("Iphone XR Icloud unlocked"); // set ad name here

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/see_more")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/category_list_row_text"));

By path10 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Cell Phones']");

driver.findElement(path10).click();

By path11 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Description']");

driver.findElement(path11).sendKeys("");
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/conditionSeekBar")).sendKeys(new CharSequence[] { " " });

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();

By path12 = By.xpath("//*[@text='$0']");

driver.findElement(path12).sendKeys("200");
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/firmPrice")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/footer_button")).click();

driver.closeApp();
Thread.sleep(50000); 

} while (index > 0);
    index = index + 1;



}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to tap on the images in the grid layout. Here is the steps to achieve that.

1. Identify the grid element.
2. Add the row to a list.
3. Then traverse to each row to click on the image element.

Below is the code function which helps to achieve it.

```
public void selectPhotos(int numberOfPhotosToSelect){

            //Find the grid element
            WebElement gridAlbum= driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the full grid of album"));

            //Add the rows of element to the list
            List<WebElement> gridRows=gridAlbum.findElements(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the row element");

           //find the number of rows
            System.out.println("Number of Rows"+gridRows.size());

            for(WebElement row:gridRows) {

                List<WebElement> cells=row.findElements(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the Image");

                for(WebElement cell:cells) {

                    if(numberOfPhotosToSelect>0) {
                    cell.click();
                    numberOfPhotosToSelect--;
                    }
                    else
                      break;

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Okay thank you but, where would I put this into my code?

Comment: Instead of creating function, use the code snippet available inside the method. Replace the code to click on the image with the code which i have mentioned above.

Comment: Things dont seem to be working, After I plug in my xpaths, I keep getting a **java.lang.ClassCastException** at this line **List<WebElement> gridRows=gridAlbum.findElements(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the row element");**

Comment: Add correct xpath for row element. Row element means element with one or more elements in one row. From your XML, I can understand that frame layout is the row element.

Comment: at **findElements** this is what appears : **The method findElements(By) in the type MobileElement is not applicable for the arguments (WebElement)**

Comment: That means you are not passing By.xpath rather you are passing WebElement object as the argument for findElements method. Check are you passing By.xpath correctly or not.